# JavaScript Module Pattern across multiple files

Tags: closures

I'm having to restructure some ancient code, and there's quite a bit of it in lots of different files. The approach is to use the revealing module pattern, as described in [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) (section Cross-File Private State).

The first function expression works great, and I can see in Firebug that the function components are also assigned correctly in the second block. But then the variable suddenly ends up undefined.

I put together a simplified [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5ag14n/), and the console shows the variable is undefined after the second assignment.

```
var test = (function ($, ns, undefined)
{
    function test1()
    {
        console.log("executing test1");
        ns.testx.test2();
    }
    return { test1: test1 };
}(jQuery, test || {}));

console.log(test);

var test = (function ($, ns, undefined)
{
    ns.testx = (function ()
    {
        function test2()
        {
        console.log("executing test2");
        }
        return { test2: test2 }
    })();
}(jQuery, test || {}));

console.log(test);

// DOM ready
$(function ()
{
    test.test1();
});
```

Several variations, such as defining the variable just once at the top don't work either. If the two function expressions are swapped, test 1 is executed but ns.testx is undefined.

I fear I'm missing the blindingly obvious and would really like to understand why this does not work. I also need to get it to work, so any help is greatly appreciated (merging the files into one is not an option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var test = (function ($, ns, undefined)
{
    function test1()
    {
        console.log("executing test1");
        ns.testx.test2();
    }
    ns.test1 = test1;
    return ns;
}(jQuery, test || {}));

console.log(test);

var test = (function ($, ns, undefined)
{
    ns.testx = (function ()
    {
        function test2()
        {
        console.log("executing test2");
        }
        return { test2: test2 }
    })();

    return ns;
    /*
      This will be
      {
        test1: test1,
        testx: {
          test2: test2
        }
      }
    */
}(jQuery, test || {}));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, and I had in fact briefly considered trying something like this but discarded the thought due to the following reasoning: ns to my understanding is an object passed by reference; as such it should be possible to assign without having to return ns; before I mark this as answered, could you please explain why ns scope is limited to the function / why ns has to be returned?

Comment: As you say, objects are passed by reference. The problem is that you are assigning a new value to it on the second "var test = ...". In the case you have avoided that variable assignment (just removing "var test = .." and using only the self-executable function), it would have work even if you removed the "return ns' statement inside it.

Comment: Thanks - out of curiosity I just ran it without the return statement, and it does not work; so I'm still not entirely clear on why it's needed. I marked your answer anyway since it helped me get it fixed.

Comment: if you take out the return in the first part it doesn't - so why need one and not the other? It should just be a ref in the first part as well.

Comment: Because in the first part the object is just declared. Doing var test = ... is the same of doing var test; test = ... (check variable hoisting). So, in that case, test is undefined until you assign it a value.

Comment: Yes, I know about hoisting, but it still doesn't make sense to me since the parameter passed in is 'test || {}', so it should always already have a valid object ref. I must be missing the obvious...

Comment: Yes, but you are passing test | {} and, in this case, as it is undefined yet, it will be {}. If you don't return, you are not assigning anything to test, you are just adding "test1" to an empty object.

Comment: yes, sorry, of course it makes sense (the relentless sun fried my brain methinks); thanks for your help!